# How to use asynchrony on the .Net WebService server?

Tags: asynchronous

server code:

```
        [WebMethod(Description = "test")]
        public async Task<string> ConnectAsyncTest()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            return "test";
        }
```

client code:

```
            CWebServiceSoapClient client = new CWebServiceSoapClient();
            var res = await client.ConnectAsyncTestAsync();
            var result = res.Body.ConnectAsyncTestResult;
```

but the result type is 'TaskOfString', not 'String'.

i want to get the type is 'String'

Answer (score 0):

ASMX was officially declared a "legacy technology" in 2009. In fact, WCF (also a legacy technology now) was released in 2006 as the replacement for ASMX. You're not going to get out-of-the-box support for `async` in ASMX.

However, ASMX does have its own style of asynchrony, which (with some work) can be compatible with `async`/`await`.

First, you'll need to run on .NET Framework 4.5 or newer, *and* [set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to 4.5 or newer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). If you cannot upgrade to .NET 4.5 yet, then full stop: you cannot use `async` or `await` ***at all***.

Then, you can use a fairly standard [APM-over-TAP wrapper pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#from-tap-to-apm), as such:

```
private async Task<string> ConnectAsyncTestAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(3000);
  return "test";
}

[WebMethod(Description = "test")]
public IAsyncResult BeginConnectAsyncTest(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(state);
  var task = ConnectAsyncTestAsync(arg);
  ExtractResultWhenComplete();
  return tcs.Task;

  async void ExtractResultWhenComplete()
  {
    try { tcs.TrySetResult(await task); }
    catch (Exception ex) { tcs.TrySetException(ex); }
    callback?.Invoke(tcs.Task);
  }
}

[WebMethod]
public string EndConnectAsyncTest(IAsyncResult result)
{
  return ((Task<string>)result).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```